# 'InlineAssignHelper' is not declared When Converting C# To VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

Here is my code in C#:

```
 ListBox l = new ListBox();
        foreach (string[] s in Regex.Matches(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/search-229092"), @"(?:<td class=""leftborder timestamp""(?s).+?<style>)((?s).+?)\s*<td>\s+(\d{2,5})</td>").Cast<Match>().Select(m => new string[] { m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value }))
        {
            Regex.Matches(s[0], @"\.([^\{]+)\{([^\}]+)\}").Cast<Match>().ToList().ForEach(m => s[0] = s[0].Replace(string.Format(@"class=""{0}""", m.Groups[1].Value), string.Format(@"style=""{0}""", m.Groups[2].Value)));
```

Now here is what codes out after I converted it using [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb):

```
     Dim l As New ListBox()
    For Each s As String() In Regex.Matches(New WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/search-229092"), "(?:<td class=""leftborder timestamp""(?s).+?<style>)((?s).+?)\s*<td>\s+(\d{2,5})</td>").Cast(Of Match)().[Select](Function(m) New String() {m.Groups(1).Value, m.Groups(2).Value})
        Regex.Matches(s(0), "\.([^\{]+)\{([^\}]+)\}").Cast(Of Match)().ToList().ForEach(Function(m) InlineAssignHelper(s(0), s(0).Replace(String.Format("class=""{0}""", m.Groups(1).Value), String.Format("style=""{0}""", m.Groups(2).Value))))
        l.Items.Add(String.Concat(Regex.Matches(Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(s(0), "<(span|div) style=""display:none"">[\d\.]+</\1>", String.Empty).Remove(0, s(0).IndexOf("/style>")), "class=""\d+""", String.Empty), "[\d\.]+").Cast(Of Match)().[Select](Function(m) m.Value)) & ":" & s(1))
    Next
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
Error   1   'InlineAssignHelper' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

What should `InlineAssingHelper` be?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Add a function something like this:

```
Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
  target = value
  Return value
End Function
```

Comment: May not be a real question, but this is a real answer.  Thanks, xpda.